# Regex javascript, why dot and comma are matching for \

Tags: javascript, regex

Why this regex `'^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$'` match for 12.2 and 12,2 ?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmKJd/)

```
var dot = '12.2',
    comma = '12,2',
    regex = '^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$';

alert( dot.match(regex) );
alert( comma.match(regex) );
```

While it works on [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Because the variable `regex` is a string the escape sequence `\.` is just `.`, which matches any character (except newline).  If you change the definition of regex to use RegExp literal syntax or escape the escape character (`\\.`) then it will work as you expect.

```
var dot = '12.2'
  , comma = '12,2'
  , regex = /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/;
      // or '^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$'
alert(dot.match(regex));
alert(comma.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 12):

Are you sure you don't need to escape the back-slash?  It is in a string, you know...

```
regex = /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/
```

or

```
regex = "^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$"
```

Actually, I'd recommend that you write it this way:

```
regex = /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you write your regex in a string, you need to escape the slash.

`regex = '^[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*$';`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be

```
regex = /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/;
```

Consult https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp for proper syntax.

Comment: Hi @Cristian, could you be possible to add a concat variable to the expression?

Comment: @inane I'm not sure what you mean :)

Comment: Ok..  i need to validate a input with only numbers and decimal notation (this field is dynamic depending country)