# Javascript function need allow numbers, dot and comma

Tags: javascript, regex, function, numbers

I need to create a function to allow numbers dot and comma. So anyone corrects the following function

```
function on(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Firstly your regex currently doesn't allow comma, which is your requirement.

Secondly, you haven't used any quantifier, so your regex will match only a single character - one of `[0-9]` or a `dot`. You need to use a quantifier.

Thirdly, instead of using `pipe`, you can move all characters inside the character class only.

Try using the below regex:

```
/^[0-9.,]+$/
```

Quantifier `+` is used to match 1 or more occurrence of the pattern.
`^` and `$` anchors match the beginning, and end of the string respectively.

Comment: Is there a way to limit only one dot or one comma? In your regex, 12.34,45 is correct

Comment: I assume  that for the most cases we have to use `/^[0-9.,]*$/`

Answer (score 7):

No need for JavaScript:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9.,]+" title="Please enter a valid decimal number." />
```

Modern browsers will handle this perfectly.

If you want to specifically allow commas as thousand separators and a single decimal point, try this:

```
... pattern="\d{1,2}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?" ...
```

Note that I am firmly against blocking user input. They should be able to type what they want, and then told if they enter something invalid.

Answer (score 6):

Your regex is incorrect.

```
var regex = /^[0-9.,]+$/;
```

[Regex javascript, why dot and comma are matching for \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469641/regex-javascript-why-dot-and-comma-are-matching-for)

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 6):

This is the best solution, in my opinion, covers more cases of inputs and allow floats.

```
     $( ".numerical" ).on('input', function() { 
                var value=$(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.,]*/g, '');
                value=value.replace(/\.{2,}/g, '.');
                value=value.replace(/\.,/g, ',');
                value=value.replace(/\,\./g, ',');
                value=value.replace(/\,{2,}/g, ',');
                value=value.replace(/\.[0-9]+\./g, '.');
                $(this).val(value)

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `/^[0-9.,]+$/`  is not work 
If not, then you could do something like this:

```
/^(?:[\d-]*,?[\d-]*\.?[\d-]*|[\d-]*\.[\d-]*,[\d-]*)$/
```

Comment: this not allowed to use negative numbers.

Comment: This one works great for decimals and periods! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Regex that I made for numbers following format of `COMMA9.2`

**Example**

1. `1,350.88`
2. `120.00`
3. `1,500,999.24`
4. `100`
5. `10000000`

**RegEx**

`^(\d+|\d{1,3},\d{3}|\d{1,3},\d{3},\d{3}|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d+)$`