# Regex for only allowing letters, numbers, and commas?

Tags: regex

I have a label name called "Color Scheme" and an input showing you the HEX colors that you just inputted.

I have limited the max length to 27 so when they input their HEX colors, like this `222222,000000,999999,ffeb00`. By default, I put the commas in myself, but I want the regex to automatically input a comma to the end of the HEX color and only allow letters, numbers, and commas.

Does anyone the regex code for this?

Comment: Show us the `regex` you've tried

Comment: @Tushar I used this code `/^\d(?:,\d)*$/`. I got this code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18033103/5124044)

Comment: Consider the string "FFEEBB" - is that a single hex-number? Why should it not be interpreted as "FFE,EBB" in the abbreviated form and how shuld the regex recognize end of hex? Just every 6 chars?

Comment: @MBaas, its not a single hex-number. I made the input to only have 4 inputs of HEX colors by limiting the max length. And I needed was the regex, but my answer is already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hex values are always 6 chars long, try this:

```
^([0-9a-fA-F]{6}(,|$)){4}
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/3JPwETiuWL).

Comment: Also use `case-insensitive` flag

Comment: @Tushar the regex is case insensitive already. using the flag takes 1 more character in the regex `A-F` vs `(?i)`, or requires using a modifier flag parameter, which not all languages support. This regex works everywhere as is.