# How to make input field to accept only numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a input field which is of type number so that it can accept numbers only
-I am using regex to restrict user to enter special characters
-it is working fine on system,but on small device as in my mobile phone the keypad type is only number,but when i am clicking on - it is taking that which 
i don't want

**What i have done**

```js
$('#test').on('keypress', function(event) {

  var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
  var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="test">
```

It is showing up like this on mobile

[image: this]

-i have tried regex to restrict it but not working on phone

**Edit**
I am almost close, i am trying below code,but it is taking minus `-` first time when i press not the next time,like if i enter 55 then i press `-` it is not taking it but when i press `-` before any number it is taking

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
    return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      }
    });
  };
}(jQuery));




$("#uintTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {


  return ^\d + [.] ? \d + $.test(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="uintTextBox" type="tel">
```

Comment: first check if the right js is loaded while browsing in phone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753548/keycode-on-android-is-always-229

Comment: @brk yup everything is correct

Comment: why negative votes i didn't get you all :(

Comment: Try using this regex: `^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$`. It will only allow decimal numbers upto 2 precision.

Comment: @RahulSharma i don't have any issue with decimal precision, issue is it is taking `-` as input on mobiles

Comment: Did you try the above regex?

Comment: @RahulSharma yup it is taking `-` as input

Comment: Try this: `<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">` while creating your input field.

Comment: @RahulSharma this one is taking `-` even on desktop also while using keyboard

Comment: Is it taking any other special characters?

Comment: Or try using the TEL input type to restrict only numbers: `<input type="tel">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190622/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-rahul-sharma).

Comment: @RahulSharma sir i have edited my post whenever you get some time please check

Comment: In you regex, remove the `-` at the beginning.

Comment: @RahulSharma i am doing like this `return /^?\d*[.]?\d*$/.test(value);` but it says on console as error nothing to repeat

Comment: I have updated your regex: `^\d+[.]?\d+$`

Comment: @RahulSharma it says syntax error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '^'`

Comment: How are you trying to use your regex? Can you show me that code here?

Comment: @RahulSharma sir i have include a new snippet,please check

Comment: See this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uhkv65yj/

Comment: @RahulSharma yup it worked thanx :),i was using wrong regex pattern,please upload an answer so that i can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression to not allow `-` character in the beginning with the `<input type="tel">`:

```
/^\d*[.]?\d*$/
```

Please see working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uhkv65yj/

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* Function allows only numbers and decimal */
$(document).on('keypress','#test',function(eve) {
    if ((  eve.which != 45 ||eve.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1 ) 
         && ( eve.which <  48 || eve.which > 57 ) 
         || ( $(this).val().indexOf('.') == 0) 
       )
       {
            eve.preventDefault();
       }
 })
```

Comment: just try it.please post the result

Comment: it is taking `-` on mobile

Comment: nop, it is not taking commas but it is taking `-` like i have uploaded the image

Comment: <input type="text" pattern="[0-9.,]+" title="Please enter a valid decimal number." />  refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033088/javascript-function-need-allow-numbers-dot-and-comma

Comment: have you found anything

Comment: he i have edited my post please check once if you get some time

Comment: try to get the keycode for '-' and restrict it,it may be the solution

Comment: can't it be done by modifying my regex `return /^-?\d*[.]?\d*$/.test(value);`

Comment: the above code is working in fiddle. i have not tested it in mobile.i am not sure about the soln.sorry

Comment: it is taking - in desktop also

Comment: The Unicode value of - is  45 try this in if condition

Comment: can you help me modifying the new regex which i have edited